# Various applications crashing with SIGSEGV, diagnosed memory issues

Tags: ram, crash

#### Issue description

For several months I am experiencing crashes of many different applications with SIGSEGV error. Applications are:

- browsers (Firefox, Brave, Chrome, Vivaldi)
- JetBrains IDEs (Pycharm, IntelliJ)
- LibreOffice
- heavy Python scripts (machine learning)
- Spring framework

[Example error log from IntelliJ](https://pastebin.com/hv3nUbHu)

So basically it's almost everything I use. Crashes do not happen right after system start but always after a few hours of light usage (browser, light programming) or soon after running some heavy scripts several times, launching Spring, etc.

The workaround is system reboot, but as you can imagine, it's quite annoying, especially when I have many applications opened.

The important thing is, **I do not experience any issues on Windows** which I am using for gaming (heavy games too - Control, AC: Odyssey).

[PC specification](https://anamitrpcspecs.tiiny.site/)

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
KDE Plasma 5.18.5
Kernel 5.4.0-66-generic

#### What I tried

1. Disabled KDE Plasma 5 activities as at first I suspected the issue has something to do with desktop. Not sure, but maybe helped a little in that crashes started occurring less sooner after system start.
2. Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6448318/7247970) I started testing my memory. Command `memtester 1024 5` returned a lot of errors like:

   `FAILURE: 0x78df55bfffffabf4 != 0x28df55bfffffabf4 at offset 0x05c425e8.`

   [Memtester output beginning](https://pastebin.com/F5ztwbhx)

   Windows Memory Diagnostic also returned errors:

   [Windows Memory Diagnostic error output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gd5ip56ffh3edz2/memory%20error.evtx?dl=0)
3. I reseated RAM changing its modules places.

#### Question

Is there anything I can do besides filing a complaint and returning RAM or switching to working on Windows?

As I understand to not be deprived of my workstation I would have to buy replacement RAM for the time being, so it's quite costly operation.

Could it be a hard drive issue? Windows and Ubuntu share RAM but Ubuntu is installed on completely separate, fast NVMe drive.

(just kidding with switching to Windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a RAM issue I have seen this a lot. You do say windows tests also fail so it is not a Ubuntu only issue. If you want it fixed replace the RAM.